# 504 error with launching Google Cloud AI Platform Notebook with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When creating [new notebook instance](https://console.cloud.google.com/mlengine/notebooks/create-instance) with Tensorflow 2.0 without GPU option on Google AI platform, I got 504 error after clicking "Open JupyterLab". It only occurs to Tensorflow 2.0.  The option of Tensorflow Enterprise 1.15 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed a few hours later after I reported the problem, hence believed to be on the Google's end.